# Using numerical/categorical data and image data to detect objects

Tags: deep-learning

Let's say that I want to create a program capable of detecting lamps on some pictures. Those pictures can be, for instance, of a room, a street, etc.

I would like to know if the following is possible:

- Create a program that is trained using both pictures of lamps (so a dataset of images) and numerical/categorical data of lamps (so that would be a .csv file which contains features ranging from type, height, etc.)
  The idea is to combine both types of data in order to detect on another unseen picture if it contains a lamp.

I'm not entirely sure if the resulting algorithm will be performant, but I would like to try.

If what I described above is possible, could you please point me in the right direction as to which literature to consult ? My research have lead me nowhere.

Comment: Welcome to Ai Community,however..,I kindly request you to first go through our community guidelines - [help](https://ai.stackexchange.com/help). For effective feedback.

Comment: i dont think those categorical data are useful, they might be actually labels like after object detection of lamps, classify them into 'types'